# How to get nearest great integer in bash?

Tags: bash, rounding

I need a function that rounds float number to nearest great integer:

```
# input -> output
14.72 -> 15
14.01 -> 15
14.00 -> 14
```

How to do this ?

Comment: You can try `LC_ALL=C printf '%.0f' "$test"` where `$test` is you variable.

Comment: it works, thanks :)